# Create online sheets using C#, SQLServer and AngularJS

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, google-sheets

I want to achieve the following -

1)Connect to SQL Server Database to get JSON data.
2)Use the JSON data to create spreadsheet like tables with multiple tabs.
3)The spreadsheet can be edited to have additional calculated features like math functions etc.
4)Create another tab depending on data present in the spreadsheet tabs
5)Publish this spreadsheet as a view only spreadsheet.

Is this possible? I am open to use any JS library.

I am looking for any excel like application which gives us the opportunity to create the spreadsheet with multiple tab + formulas and share/socialize it.

What is the best way/example to go about implementing this feature? I want it to work with AngularJS, JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried this [Quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/dotnet)?

Comment: Yes. I will check it out. I have modified the question though. I am looking for any excel like application which gives us the opportunity to create the spreadsheet with multiple tab + formulas and share/socialize it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use Sheets API? Or what exactly are your requirements in this matter?

Comment: Open to use any API. As long as I can create an online spreasheet in HTML and publish it as a HTML.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

#### Like mentioned previously, the best solution for this would be to start with the Sheets API Quickstart for .NET [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/dotnet).

After you start getting a grasp on how the Sheets API works, you can easily connect to the SQL Server and retrieve the data you want in order to create a spreadsheet with your requirements.

You might find the following links useful:

- [spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) - request to create a spreadsheet which will return the newly created spreadsheet
- [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) - request to write multiple values in a spreadsheet
- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) - request to append values to a spreadsheet

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/dotnet);
- [Google Sheets API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/sheets/v4).